# How to add hh:mm:ss in Sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

table Column  is :

```
time         date 
-----        ------------- 

21:02:03     2/1/2018
22:05:13     2/1/2018
20:25:13     2/1/2018
```

I want to add only time `21:02:03 + 22:05:13 + 20:25:13 = 63:32:29`  for a particular date
output as `63:32:29`

table name is schedule

I need a query for Sum of total time.

Comment: what will be the output if the sum of time is greater than 24 hour?

Comment: If I want to add a time for  24:02:03 + 24:05:13 + 04:25:59 = 54:37:00 Because i am calculating a count down Time

Comment: Pick your platform `mysql` ***is not the same as*** `Sql Server`! (And `C#` is only relevant if you intend doing the calculation in code.)

Comment: Given the wide variety of answers, all guessing in the dark what OP might actually be asking; I'd say the question is pretty unclear. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the time to seconds and SUM up that values

```
SELECT DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, 0, [timecolumn])), 0)
```

Or, just calculate the count down time in seconds, and convert it to your format

```
SELECT count_down_sec = SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '0:00:00', [timecolumn]))
```

Full query here

```
SELECT CAST(tottime /60/60 AS nvarchar) 
                +':'+CAST(tottime /60%60 AS nvarchar) 
                +':'+ CAST(tottime % 60 AS nvarchar)    
FROM    (
    SELECT  SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, [time])) AS tottime
    FROM    [schedule] 
    WHERE   [date]='2/1/2018'
)   AS T
```

Output:

```
count_down_sec
63:32:29
```

Comment: Query is working fine but after 24hrs mean it will not working ,i want to come like that 28:07:27 (HH:MM:SS)

Comment: @MariappanSiddan, please check the modified result.

Comment: But your query is given by statically , I need to total time for particular date and particular column name

Comment: :) you can replace that there

Comment: When i am using a Stored Procedure it will come to this error how can i solve it  "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.' "

Comment: what is the data type of your `[time]` column? I think there may be a wrong value.

Comment: [time] column datatype is "time" only

Answer (score 1):

Just try this,

```
SELECT  
IFNULL(SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `time1` ) ) ),'00:00:00') AS Time 
FROM schedule ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the SUM function to the column you want to add time (assuming the data type of the column is TIME).

https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/sum.php

Comment: It's not working for time data type          "select  SUM(time) FROM time where date = '2/1/2018' "            it will come to this warning     Operand data type time is invalid for sum operator.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use the below sql,

```
SELECT date(timedatecol) date1,
       sec_to_time(SUM(time_to_sec(time(timedatecol)))) timetotal
FROM schedule
GROUP BY date1;
```

Below are the details:

```
CREATE TABLE `schedule` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timedatecol` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

Inserted Data:
'1', '2018-02-02 06:19:05'
'2', '2018-02-02 06:19:06'
'3', '2018-02-02 06:19:07'
'4', '2018-02-03 06:19:08'
'5', '2018-02-03 06:19:08'
'6', '2018-02-04 06:19:08'
'7', '2018-02-04 06:19:09'
'8', '2018-02-02 06:19:09'
```

output for below sql

```
    SELECT date(timedatecol) date1,
       sec_to_time(SUM(time_to_sec(time(timedatecol)))) timetotal
FROM schedule
GROUP BY date1;

date1          timetotal

'2018-02-02', '25:16:27'
'2018-02-03', '12:38:16'
'2018-02-04', '12:38:17'
```

Comment: Can you Give me a query for Mysql instead to Sql Server..??

Comment: Above query is for Mysql, not for Sql Server.

Comment: Yes bro but i need Sql server query

Comment: omg... please edit your tags, remove mysql, (even c#... as it seems it's unrelated). And next time put a little more effort on your question, having to guess what you're asking doesn't encourage people to answer

Answer (score 0):

try This approach

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    MyTime TIME,
    MyDate DATE DEFAULT('2/1/2018')
)

INSERT INTO @T(MyTime)
VALUES('01:02:03'),('01:05:13'),('03:25:59')

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
       MyDate,
       NewTime = CAST(MyDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(MyTime AS DATETIME)
       FROM @T
),C2
AS
(
    SELECT
       MyDate,
       MyMin = SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MyDate, NewTime))
       FROM CTE
          GROUP BY MyDate
)
SELECT
    MyDate,
    CAST(MyDate AS DATETIME)+CAST(RTRIM(MyMin/60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(MyMin%60),2) AS DATETIME)
    FROM C2
```

My Result

```
MyDate     MyTime
---------- -----------------------
2018-02-01 2018-02-01 05:32:00.000
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try like this

```
    select dateadd(second,datediff(second,0,time1),time2) as Time3 from your_table
```

I think this will work

Comment: given Query is working  but i need calculate a particular date so u have given query is time1 and time2 but i need to above table column